# Datatype for latitude and longitude in doctrine2

Tags: google-maps, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to show location in Google Map.

I am using Symfony2, doctrine and MySQL.

Need help in what is the right type in yml/doctrine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you know which types coordinates are?

Comment: latitude and longitude -- float (9,6)

Comment: So, what's the problem to find the type ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the Doctrine Docs:

> **decimal**
>   Maps and converts numeric data with fixed-point precision. If you need an exact precision for numbers with fractions, you should consider using this type.

As a result I use decimal for Latitude and Longitude in Doctrine. I can confirm that Decimal with a precision of 20 and a scale of 16 works.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal", precision=20, scale=16)
 */
private $latitude;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="decimal", precision=20, scale=16)
 */
private $longitude;
```

Comment: precision=20, scale=16? either you're handing out floating point variables, or you've built a database to track individual atoms

Comment: Latitude and longitude are conventionally given as floating point numbers with a lot of decimal places. This is why they can be tricky from a data storage point of view. Check it out: https://www.latlong.net/

Comment: Yeah, I was referencing [this](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/images/8/88/coordinate_precision.png)

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I see your point! Yes, I don't know why the database I was working on had such specific lat / long values. Sure, feel free to lower the specificity for most applications.

Answer (score -2):

I would use an "object" data type and save an own-typed object with the location info in it.

You could create an object named "Location" which implements an interface that forces it to have a latitude and longitude, then use:

```
$location = new \Location();
$location->setLatitude($lat);
$location->setLongitude($long);

$entity->setLocation($location);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was able to resolve the issue.
I declared the type as float(10,6) for latitude and longitude. But the DB update through doctrine update was giving error. Looks like bug in Doctrine.
I created the columns manually in the table and it is working fine now.